# How are thread pools "mapped" to future executions in Spring?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, spring-mvc, asynchronous

Consider a code:

```
@Autowired
private AsyncRestOperations restTemplate;

@RequestMapping("/abcd")
public CompletableFuture<Result> process(HttpRequest request) {
    convertListenableFutureToCompletableFuture(restTemplate.getForEntity("http://...", Result.class))
        .thenApply(/*Some logic here*/)
        .thenCompose(/*Some logic returns future*/)
}
```

Here I can see the following processing order:

1. Spring receive a request to `DispatcherServlet`.
2. The `DispatcherServlet` determines handler and pass request to it.
3. `process` method is invoked
4. `restTemplate.getForEntity` is called.
5. `thenApply` is called
6. `thenCompose` is called
7. CompletableFuture is "returned" back to `DispatcherServlet` (or to other Spring component)

As I understand points `1-3` and `7` are executed in same Thread pool (Am i Right?).

But what thread (pools) are used to execute points `4-6`?

Comment: If you post up the configuration for your restTemplate bean (we can only see the interface definition), it should be possible to tell you exactly what happens once step 4 is called.

Comment: It is just Spring rest async template, which is created like that `new AsyncRestTemplate()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- 1-3 & 7 are executed on the same thread (as is the call to 4)
- 5,6 are executed on the same thread as each other, which is the same thread that provides the CompletableFuture result (in step 4 and is most likely *not* the same thread used to make the call to the restTemplate).
- AsyncRestOperations is an interface, so what happens inside will depend on the underlying implementation.
- If you were using an NIO Rest Client, the Rest call will be executed on the NIO client's internal event loop pool (as will 5&6 which is probably not what you want - see thenApplyAsync, followed by thenCompose).
- You are using an Async Blocking I/O Rest client & normally the call will be executed on a thread in it's configured thread pool - unfortunately the default behaviour on the class you are using is not to configure a thread pool but use a new thread each time - see below - (5&6 executing on the same thread here is probably fine and even optimal).

**UPDATE**

Based on further info : The example is using AsyncRestTemplate which is

> Spring's central class for asynchronous client-side HTTP access.
>   ...
>
> Note: by default AsyncRestTemplate relies on standard JDK facilities
>   to establish HTTP connections. You can switch to use a different HTTP
>   library such as Apache HttpComponents, Netty, and OkHttp by using a
>   constructor accepting an AsyncClientHttpRequestFactory.

AsyncRestTemplate makes use of Spring's SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor (When instantiated via the default constructor) which

> TaskExecutor implementation that fires up a new Thread for each task,
>   executing it asynchronously. Supports limiting concurrent threads
>   through the "concurrencyLimit" bean property. By default, the number
>   of concurrent threads is unlimited.
>
> NOTE: This implementation does not reuse threads! Consider a
>   thread-pooling TaskExecutor implementation instead, in particular for
>   executing a large number of short-lived tasks.

The later part is probably sub-optimal, I would configure AsyncRestTemplate to use your own thread pool.

Comment: I read about `*Async` methods in `CompletableFuture`, but what `Executor` I should use for them? Does spring have one for theseme or I should create a new bean with thread pool, autowire it and use pool from it?

Comment: Yes, I think you have to use one of the Spring managed ones, as the other constructor takes a Spring Interface. e.g. new AsyncRestTemplate(new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor() ); - which creates an unsized Thread Pool. There is ThreadPoolExecutorFactoryBean which can be used to configure JDK ExecutorServices in some manner.

Comment: @Cherry - you don't need the *Async methods in CompletableFuture in this case. Submission to the a task executor is ~ 10X slower than executing on the same thread (for identity function application). Because you aren't using NIO, resuing the thread from the Async Rest call is fine.